# SSH.NET - send command

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi

I'm making a program which uses SSH.NET but I don't know how to send a command to SSH server. Here is my current code and I need to add code which sends a command. `SshClient raspberry = new SshClient(ip, 22, "pi", "raspberry");
                    raspberry.Connect();
                    MessageBox.Show("Connected");
                    ovladani oknoovladani = new ovladani();
                    oknoovladani.Show();`

Answer (score 0):

I think you would set up your command by cmd = sshclient.CreateCommand(...) and then execute via cmd.Execute().